# Flex : How to link data to a datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, flash-builder

I'm following flex tutorials but i'm not doing exactly as they do, so :

*What i want*

I have an input text, with a button 'search'.

**I want when this button is clicked that the data returned by the function search are displayed in the datagrid.**

*What i have :*

The text input :

```
<s:TextInput includeIn="DetailServeurs" x="58" y="361" width="209" id="txt_search" text="Default text" focusIn="txt_search_focusInHandler(event)"/>
```

a Search button :

```
<s:Button includeIn="DetailServeurs" x="275" y="361" label="Rechercher" id="btn_rechercher" click="btn_rechercher_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

a clickhandler for this search button  :

```
protected function btn_rechercher_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(txt_search.text != ""){
                getServeurByNameResult.token = serveurService.getServeurByName(txt_search.text);
            }
        }
```

and a datagrid :

```
<mx:DataGrid includeIn="DetailServeurs" x="30" y="124" width="1002" height="179" id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{getServeurByNameResult.lastResult}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="GSP_nom" dataField="GSP_nom"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="port" dataField="port"/>
               ........
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

So how can i display the results in the datagrid ? Thanks ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. I can't tell you exactly why but i got helped.